How to keep items which was loaded when Load More button was clicked
I'm new to React.
I have a list of products, and by default, it shows 15 products. When I click on the 'Load More' button, it displays another 15 items, making a total of 30 items. However, when I click on an item that was displayed after clicking the 'Load More' button and then navigate to the product detail page, upon returning to the list page, it shows a random spot on the page as the loaded products are now gone. How do I keep the products that were loaded after the button was clicked so that when I return from the product detail page, I can come back to the spot where the clicked item is displayed?
[Edit]
This is the part I think I might have to modify.
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [loadingProducts, setLoadingProducts] = useState(true);
    const [loadingMore, setLoadingMore] = useState(false);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

    const handleLoadMore = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setCurrentPage(previousCurrentPage => previousCurrentPage + 1);
        setLoadingMore(true);
    };

    <LoadMore
        loadingMore={loadingMore}
        handleLoadMore={handleLoadMore}
        meta={meta}
        numberVisibleProducts={products.length}
    />



Share a code sample on the component rendering the products

The reason why your fetched data doesn't appear is because when the component responsible for fetching the data is rendered, it initially sets the "page" value to 1, like this:


const [page, setPage] = useState(1)



If you want to remember the current page, you need to store it, for example in localStorage or sessionStorage. Then, whenever that page loads, you can retrieve the stored page count.
You can achieve this using the useLocalStorage hook from the useHooks library. This hook allows you to simulate the above behavior without encountering any issues. You can find more information in the documentation here:
useLocalStoage documentation

Thank you! It's hard to share my entire code as there's a lot of things happening in the code, but I do see const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1); in my code. When I change it to (2) it just show a list of second page rather than showing 30 items..

I added a code!
